# "String or binary data would be truncated." error after publishing on IIS7

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, iis-7, ado.net

Could you help me with the following error, which causes in my asp.net webforms application after publishing it on IIS 7 web-server.

**Error:**
There is a following error message "String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated."

**Additional details:**

- I have a table in MS SQL database to keep files uploaded by users.
- The field is set as varbinary(max)
- I run my webapp from Visual Studio Development server using the same DB from my workstation and there is no any error.
  But after publishing on IIS7 web-server I have this error.
  (Source codes, a file to upload and DB are the same)

I tried to set the exact length of SqlParameter, but result is the same.

```
Dim fileDataParam As New SqlParameter("FileData", SqlDbType.VarBinary,
     fileData.Length)
fileDataParam.Value = fileData
params.Add(fileDataParam)
```

**Please, could you give me a piece of advice what reasons can cause this error?**
**Could you recommend me what settings of IIS or MSSQL I should set or check?**

**Update:**
I run SQL Server profile in both cases.
SQL queries are the same, in the first case (on IIS) error occurs, in the second case (on my PC) - no error.

---

**Solved**

I have solved the problem. It was a truncation of a string but in another field [ServerName] (it passed short value on my PC and long value on server side.)

Comment: That error message indicates that the data you are inserting into the column is too large for the column size.  Verify that the varbinary column is indeed a `varbinary(max)`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I run application from my workstation using the same DB and the error is not appear. I transfer the same build to web-server and the error occurs.

Comment: I added a update to my question: I run SQL Server profile in both cases. SQL queries are the same, in the first case (on IIS) error occurs, in the second case (on my PC) - no error.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you accept @ps2goat comment as the answer.

The data you are inserting into the column is too large for the column size. Set the column to varbinary(MAX)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the field is varbinary(max). Moreover. it works great from my workstation on the same DB.